# MongoDB Aggregation - Field must be a accumulator object in group stage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb aggregation. Let's say I have this data:

```js
[
{
            "end_year": 2020,
            "intensity": 12,
            "sector": "Information Technology",
            "topic": "robot",
            "insight": "62 market research reports study robotics industry",
            "url": "http://robohub.org/62-market-research-reports-study-robotics-industry/",
            "region": "",
            "start_year": 2016,
            "impact": "",
            "added": "July, 16 2016 02:44:49",
            "published": "July, 11 2016 00:00:00",
            "country": "",
            "relevance": 3,
            "pestle": "Economic",
            "source": "Robothub",
            "title": "Forecasts the industrial robotics market in APAC to grow at a CAGR of 8.7% during the period 2016-2020 in the top 5 segments.",
            "likelihood": 4
        },
        {
            "end_year": "",
            "intensity": 2,
            "sector": "Government",
            "topic": "government",
            "insight": "Oil, Greed, and Grievances in the Middle East and North Africa",
            "url": "https://www.newsecuritybeat.org/2016/07/oil-greed-grievances-middle-east-north-africa/",
            "region": "",
            "start_year": "",
            "impact": "",
            "added": "July, 16 2016 01:12:21",
            "published": "July, 12 2016 00:00:00",
            "country": "",
            "relevance": 1,
            "pestle": "Political",
            "source": "New Security Beat",
            "title": "Countries threatened by larger-scale insurgencies might want to consider giving regional groups some share in central government decision-making.",
            "likelihood": 2
        }
]
```

This is my query:

```js
// return all the countries associated with a single topic
const data = await  Data.aggregate([
        { $match: {} },
        { $group: { _id: "$topic",country: ["$country"],likelihood: ["$likelihood"],relevance: ["$relevance"],intensity: ["$intensity"] } }
        ])
```

I want to return all countries,likelihoods,relevances associated with a **single/common topic**

I know how to get the first and last ones using $first and $last operators. How do I get all of them in an array?

Answer (score 0):

We can use $push operator to add all of the field values:

```js
const data = await  Data.aggregate([
        { $match: {} },
        { $group: { _id: "$topic",data: { $push: { country: "$country",likelihood: "$likelihood",relevance: "$relevance",intensity: "$intensity"   } } } }
     ])
```